# How to get a Facebook signed request ('signed_request') in Java

Tags: java, facebook

I am building an application through which on click of (GoToApp) I want to receive the `signed_request` parameter sent from a Facebook response. I have created the application, gave the necessary site and canvas URLs.

What are the steps through which I can receive the `signed_request` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the tab/canvas URL is EXACTLY the same as required. If there is a redirect to another page, then the signed request and other values will not be sent. You can check using a browser sniffer. If a call to the page responds with a 300 (301, 302, etc.) redirect, then you need to change to what it redirects to.

Examples:

`https://example.com/` may need to be `https://www.example.com/` (add www., or remove www. depending on how server is set up)

`www.example.com/` may need to be `www.example.com/index.php` (add `index.php`, or the right page).

Check you are using `http://` and `https://` correctly in the URLs, and that `https://` returns a valid page.